# Can i use loops to multiple works on Android?

Tags: java, android, loops

First of all  let me tell that am new in Android Application Development.
I am making an Application to set wallpapers, I got lots of code that repeat again and again, but a simple difference.
I used to type codes like this

```
InputStream is1 = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.wall1);
InputStream is2 = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.wall2);
InputStream is3 = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.wall3);
InputStream is4 = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.wall4);
InputStream is5 = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.wall5);
InputStream is6 = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.wall6);
InputStream is7 = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.wall7);
InputStream is8 = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.wall8);
InputStream is9 = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.wall9);
InputStream is10 = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.wall10);
InputStream is11 = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.wall11);
InputStream is12 = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.wall12);
InputStream is13 = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.wall13);
InputStream is14 = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.wall14);
InputStream is15 = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.wall15);
```

Its really annoyingg... So i used a loop like this

```
for(int i=1;i<=15;i++)
{
    InputStream is+i = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.wall+i);
}
```

but it's not working, Tell me any solution to my problem, Hop you understand what am expecting!

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of type InputStream and then you can do something like this...

InputStream[] is;

int id;

for (int i=0;i<=15;i++){

id = getResources().getIdentifier( "wall" + i, "drawable", "com.yourpackagename");

is[i] = getResources().openRawResource(id);

}

Answer (score 0):

Try SomeThing  like below :

> InputStream[] array;
>
> ```
> for(int i=1;i<=15;i++)
> {
>
>     // image from res/drawable
>   int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("my_image", 
>           "drawable", getPackageName());
>     array[i] = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.wall+i);
> }
> ```